# Angular + Express PWA 504 Gateway

Tags: angular, express, heroku, progressive-web-apps, http-status-code-504

I'm having trouble creating a PWA angular app with NodeJS + Express server.

- I'm serving my angular build --prod on a static path in Express
- I'm using routes in my Angular App
- The client manages to load `manifest.json`, `ngsw-worker.js`, `ngsw.json?ngsw-cache-bust=[RANDOM]` and all the rest of the files
- The client creates an SW and shows this gear icon on every request
- The DevTools Disable cache checkbox is disabled ;)

Yet, when I check the Offline checkbox in DevTools and refresh the page I get 504 on the requested route, and then a few  seconds later, a failed request from `ngsw-worker.js`

It's progress in my PWA app as I don't receive the Dinosaur chrome page.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

edit: Finally solved my related problem.  My issue was that when I was running my `ng build --prod`. I had added  `&& node patch.js` to fix an issue in the build file. Apparently this was messing up my service worker hash. Now that I removed it everything is working great.  Lesson being that you can't screw around with the build folder after it has been generated.

I have this exact same setup with the same problem that I have been fighting with for the past couple days.  The service worker is being created correctly and I can see all JS chunks being downloaded on first loading.  However I get the same 504 error when trying to go to a page offline that I have not already loaded while online.

One thought I was trying to look into was the "Referer" not pointing to the ngsw-worker on the 504 request.  I'm not sure if that could be an issue specific to Express with Angular PWA.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks a lot for your quick response. I see you had a specific script and I'm happy to hear that removing it helped you. In my situation, I don't have such a script.
Howerver, your point seems to be fair. I think it's something with my Express server. Not sure what though.